# Select multiple values from same column based on 2 columns

Tags: sql

Best explained using an example. My trials and results are bellow the example.

There are two tables (in reality I have multiple tables)

### TABLE: Products

```
ID    name
-----------
1    apple
2    orange
3    pear
```

### TABLE: ATTRIBUTES

```
ID  prod_ID   attr_id   value
----------------------------
1   1       101     20
2   1       102     red
3   1       103     sweet
4   2       101     30
5   2       102     orange
6   2       103     sour
6   3       101     40 
7   3       102     green
8   3       103     sweet
```

### DESIRED OUTPUT

```
name   attr_id 101 AS 'price'   attr_id 102 AS 'taste'
------------------------------------------------------
apple        20           sweet
orange       30           sour
pear         40           sweet
```

I have managed SQL till now but recently I have had to call 3 tables and combine column values like shown above. I just can't get my head wrapped around this. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to query for each column separately...

```
SELECT 
  p.name,
  (SELECT value FROM Attributes a WHERE attr_id=101 AND a.prod_ID=p.ID) AS price,
  (SELECT value FROM Attributes a WHERE attr_id=102 AND a.prod_ID=p.ID) AS taste
FROM Products p
```

... or ...
If you are using MSSQL 2008 R2 you can use PIVOT:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Since you have not mentioned any RDBMS in your question, the query below will work on most RDBMS.

```
SELECT  a.Name,
        MAX(CASE WHEN b.attr_ID = 101 THEN b.value END) Price,
        MAX(CASE WHEN b.attr_ID = 103 THEN b.value END) Taste
FROM    Products a
        INNER JOIN Attributes b
            ON a.ID = b.prod_ID
GROUP   BY a.Name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e037b/1)

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: Thanks JW. It's MySQL. I have got the code working using the bellow method. I will try using MAX(CASE too through your SQLFiddle.

Comment: `joins` are much faster than `IN` in mysql. you can see it though `EXPLAIN youSelectStatement`. do you want to know the dynamic version of this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` statement for that: (This will work in MySQL)

```
SELECT p.name
   ,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN attr_id = 101 THEN value else NULL END) AS price
   ,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN attr_id = 102 THEN value else NULL END) AS color
   ,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN attr_id = 103 THEN value else NULL END) AS taste
FROM Products p JOIN Attributes a
ON p.id = a.prod_id
GROUP BY p.name;
```

Or you can also do the same with join: (This will work in both MySQL and SQL Server)

```
SELECT Name
  ,CASE WHEN a.attr_id = 101 THEN a.value ELSE NULL END AS price
  ,CASE WHEN b.attr_id = 102 THEN b.value else NULL END AS color
  ,CASE WHEN c.attr_id = 103 THEN c.value else NULL END AS taste
FROM Products p
  LEFT JOIN Attributes a ON p.id = a.prod_id
  LEFT JOIN Attributes b ON p.id = b.prod_id AND a.attr_id = 101 AND b.attr_id = 102
  LEFT JOIN Attributes c ON p.id = c.prod_id AND a.attr_id = 101 AND c.attr_id = 103
WHERE a.attr_id IS NOT NULL and b.attr_id IS NOT NULL AND c.attr_id IS NOT NULL
```

I have also added a column for `color`.

Output

```
|   NAME | PRICE |  COLOR | TASTE |
-----------------------------------
|  apple |    20 |    red | sweet |
| orange |    30 | orange |  sour |
|   pear |    40 |  green | sweet |
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85db7/17)

#### [Demo for SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9cfd0/1)

Answer (score 0):

Using PIVOT, easier to adjust for extra attributes.

```
SELECT NAME, [101],[102],[103]
             FROM (
                    SELECT P.NAME as NAME, A.ATTR_ID as ATTR_ID, A.VALUE as VALUE
                    FROM PRODUCTS as P, ATTRIBUTES as A
                    WHERE A.PROD_ID = P.ID  
             ) SrcTable
            PIVOT 
            (
                MAX(VALUE)
                for ATTR_ID in ([101],[102],[103])
            ) PivotTable;
```

Or a dynamic statement could be generated to adjust for a variable number of attributes (since this is the only thing that changes in the above statement)

The column string could be obtained with somethings like:

```
DECLARE @columns AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
set @columns = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(ATTR_ID) 
             FROM ATTRIBUTES
             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'');
```

Next, this could variable could be used to generate a string like the static PIVOT

```
DECALARE @stmt AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
set @stmt ='SELECT NAME, ' + @columns + '
             FROM (
                    SELECT P.NAME as NAME, A.ATTR_ID as ATTR_ID, A.VALUE as VALUE 
                    FROM PRODUCTS as P, ATTRIBUTES as A 
                    WHERE A.PROD_ID = P.ID 
             ) SourceTable
             PIVOT ( 
                MAX(VALUE)
                for ATTR_ID in (' + @columns + ') 
            ) PivotTable';

EXECUTE(@stmt);
```